# Power series expansion of a function

Tags: sequences-and-series, moment-generating-functions

[image]

In this question we are asked to find the power series expansion of M(t) upto the t squared term. I understand how they've gone from step 1 to step 2, by dividing the top and bottom by p but I'm not able to understand at all how they have proceeded from step 2 to step three. Is there a general technique used to find the power series expansion for functions, how do we approach these types of questions from the start?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: There's an error at the 2nd line: the factor of $q/p$ should be $\color{red}{1+{}}t+t^2/2+\dotsm$. They replaced $e^t$ with its  Taylor's series.

Comment: that's what i initially thought as well but there's no error, this is the mgf of a negative binomial and the term(1/p)-(q/p) =(1-q)/p =p/p=1.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we do *not* divide by $p$ but instead consider the reciprocal value and take from it the reciprocal again.

> \begin{align*}
> M(t)&=\left(\frac{p}{1-qe^t}\right)^k=\left(\frac{1-qe^t}{p}\right)^{-k}\\
> &=\left(\frac{1}{p}-\frac{q}{p}\left(1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\cdots\right)\right)^{-k}\\
> &=\left(1-\frac{q}{p}\left(t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\cdots\right)\right)^{-k}\tag{1}\\
> \end{align*}

Now we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* with $\alpha=-k$
\begin{align*}
(1+z)^{-k}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{-k}{n}z^k=1+\binom{-k}{1}t+\binom{-k}{2}z^2+\cdots\\
&=1-kz+\frac{1}{2}(-k)(-k-1)z^2+\cdots
\end{align*}

> With 
>   \begin{align*}
> z:=-\frac{q}{p}\left(t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\cdots\right)
> \end{align*}
>
> we obtain from (1) 
>   \begin{align*}
> M(t)&=1+k\cdot\frac{q}{p}\left(t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\cdots\right)
> +\frac{1}{2}(-k)(-k-1)\left(\frac{q}{p}\left(t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\cdots\right)\right)^2+\cdots\\
> &=1+k\cdot\frac{q}{p}t+k\cdot\frac{q}{p}t^2/2+k(k+1)\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^2t^2/2+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>   and we obtain the wanted representation.

Two aspects which should be considered:

- Since each summand $\left(t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\cdots\right)$ starts with $t$ we do not need to consider higher powers than $2$ since then there is no longer any contribution to $t^2$ but only to higher powers of $t$.
- It is this clever transformation right at the beginning which enables us to easily find the powers up to $t^2$. If we would instead start with a $k$-th power of a *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*
  \begin{align*}
  M(t)&=\left(\frac{p}{1-qe^t}\right)^k\\
  &=\left(p\left(1+qe^t+q^2e^{2t}+\cdots\right)\right)^k\\
  &=p^k\left(1+q(1+t+t^2/2+\cdots)+q^2(1+t+t^2/2+\cdots)^2+\cdots\right)^k
  \end{align*}
  *each* of the inner summands contributes to $1,t$ and $t^2$ and this is not easily manageable.